# mongodb - search in subarray, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

i started with mongodb and played around with random temperature data
like this:

```
'weather' => array(
                    'Air' => array(
                        'Jan' => 11,
                        'Feb' => 20,
                        'Mar' => 24,
                        'Jun' => 28,
                        'Jul' => 30
                    )
                ),
```

Now my question:
How can i query the Air array ?

I knwo i can do somethin like:

```
$query = array('weather.Air.Jan' => 11);
```

Works fine...

But how can i search in the whole Air array:

```
$query = array('weather.Air.$' => 40);
```

This query doesn't work...
Can somebody help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the query you're looking for does not exist.

As written, you're asking for *"weather.Air where a key in the JSON object contains a value of 40"*.

MongoDB has the ability to "drill into" arrays. However, when it comes to sub-objects, you have to reach into the keys directly. There is no operator that provides a "search all keys" method. There is an outstanding JIRA request for this item [right here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1248).